# What robot should I use for SLAM?

Tags: navigation, ros-melodic, frontier-exploration, husky, gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am in algorithm development and I just need a robot to test on in Gazebo simulation. I have tried several robots I found online and none seem to work quite right, so I am looking for advice about a robot simulation for ROS Melodic, Gazebo 9, that is compatible with gmapping or hector, and ideally with frontier exploration (explore_lite package). My only specific sensor requirement is that it have lidar.

BTW, I have tried the Husky (bad maps, can't figure out why), the Turtlebot3 (not compatible with explore_lite because it doesn't use move_base for commands), and the Summit XL and XLS (bad localization, both).

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/318138/what-robot-should-i-use-for-slam?/) by [kitkatme](https://answers.ros.org/users/40297/kitkatme/) on ROS Answers with karma: 47 on 2019-03-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> the Turtlebot3 (not compatible with explore_lite because it doesn't use move_base for commands)

This confuses me: according to [turtlebot3_navigation](http://wiki.ros.org/turtlebot3_navigation) `move_base` is definitely used.

---

Edit:

> but when it's running the SLAM demo per virtual SLAM instructions here, and I then print the list of topics, move_base is not one of them.

`move_base` is not a topic. It's a node (edit: and an action server namespace).

> It's using move_base_simple.

This also confuses me. Are we talking about the same package? See [turtlebot3_navigation/launch/move_base.launch](https://github.com/ROBOTIS-GIT/turtlebot3/blob/4da5676fab45703e1ee5ac8b675d7f447c13489f/turtlebot3_navigation/launch/move_base.launch#L9).

Is [this](http://wiki.ros.org/move_base_simple) the `move_base_simple` you refer to, or the [topic based interface](http://wiki.ros.org/move_base#Subscribed_Topics) to `move_base`?

---

Edit 2:

I don't have time to look into the TB3 setup right now, but just to give you some pointers:

> when I run other robots like the husky, there are topics like move_base/cmd_vel, and those don't show up with turtlebot3

the topic name `cmd_vel` is a *choice*, it could be called anything. The fact that many robot configurations have it as `move_base/cmd_vel` is just their preferred setup.

Looking at the launch file I linked earlier, it would appear that `move_base` will output `Twist`s on `/cmd_vel` by default ([here](https://github.com/ROBOTIS-GIT/turtlebot3/blob/4da5676fab45703e1ee5ac8b675d7f447c13489f/turtlebot3_navigation/launch/move_base.launch#L4)).

> After your comment, I checked the node list and while running the simulation as described above, there is no move_base node either.

that would be something to check, if you're still interested in using the TB3. According to the launch file, `move_base` is definitely used, so the name should show up.

> So I think that move_base is not actually used, unless you count move_base_simple, which shows up in the topic list but not the nodes.

Well, again: `move_base_simple` is not a node, it's a topic. You should probably use `rostopic info /move_base_simple/goal` to see who is subscribing or publishing to that.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-03-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kitkatme](https://answers.ros.org/users/40297/kitkatme/) on 2019-03-11**:
confuses me too, but when it's running the SLAM demo per virtual SLAM instructions [here](http://emanual.robotis.com/docs/en/platform/turtlebot3/simulation/#turtlebot3-simulation-using-gazebo), and I then print the list of topics, move_base is not one of them. It's using move_base_simple. Maybe that still counts as move_base and that's why they list it, but explore_lite isn't set up for that. (It's worth trying to rewrite turtlebot3 to be compatible with explore_lite, but I figured I'd ask if there is anything already set up since I'm working on a deadline and very new to ROS.)

**Comment by [kitkatme](https://answers.ros.org/users/40297/kitkatme/) on 2019-03-11**:
ah, thanks for the clarification! to be more specific with the turtlebot3, when I run other robots like the husky, there are topics like move_base/cmd_vel, and those don't show up with turtlebot3. After your comment, I checked the node list and while running the simulation as described above, there is no move_base node either. Also explore_lite hangs in its initialization at the point where it's waiting to connect to move_base server. So I think that move_base is not actually used, unless you count move_base_simple, which shows up in the topic list but not the nodes.

**Comment by [kitkatme](https://answers.ros.org/users/40297/kitkatme/) on 2019-03-11**:
thanks for pointing me to that launch file!! problem solved! when I run move_base.launch in addition to the turtlebot3 SLAM and explore_lite packages, frontier exploration works.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-03-11**:
Now I'm really confused. Did you not follow the instructions in the [Virtual Navigation with TurtleBot3](http://emanual.robotis.com/docs/en/platform/turtlebot3/simulation/#virtual-navigation-with-turtlebot3) section of the manual that you linked to earlier?

**Comment by [kitkatme](https://answers.ros.org/users/40297/kitkatme/) on 2019-03-11**:
No; as mentioned, I followed the virtual SLAM instructions

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-03-11**:
`explore_lite` is essentially just sending navigation goals to a running `move_base` instance/stack (replacing a human sending it goals in a sense). So you'd have to have the nav stack running, or it won't work.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I had written this package for a similar purpose : https://github.com/YugAjmera/navros_pkg
It might be  useful !

---

Originally posted by [Yug Ajmera](https://answers.ros.org/users/39769/yug-ajmera/) with karma: 19 on 2019-03-11

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kitkatme](https://answers.ros.org/users/40297/kitkatme/) on 2019-03-11**:
thanks, I'll check it out!!